# Is it possible to configure Postfix to receive emails on any email address on a domain name I control?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

The question is mainly stated on the title. I was wondering if it is possible to configure Postfix in such way. More specifically, if I control domain "example.com" I'm asking if I will be able to see all the received emails, such as "aaa@example.com", "aab@example.com" without any kind of "creating an email account locally". Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You mean [like this](https://tecadmin.net/setup-catch-all-email-account-in-postfix/)?

Comment: @larsks Exactly, if you can make an answer about it I will accept it.